# Firegento - how to add store address to the header (VAT compliance)

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, vat

Could somebody help me with **Firegento PDF**. The problem is that original **Magento PDF invoice** includes store address in the header.
 BUT, despite German contributors (they come from VAT EU country) Firegento doesn't include this important data.
So the Firegento invoices are not meeting EU VAT standards without store(sender) full address.

How to include standard Magento store address from original PDF to Firegento header?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it in the header, you will have to modify the extension.

However, you can include the address in the footer. This will at least meet the law-requirements.

Go to `System -> Configuration -> PDF print-outs -> PDF Creation` and set it to "Yes".

You can also go to `System -> Configuration -> PDF print-outs -> Invoice` and add your VAT Id & address in "Note" if you prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

Under `System > Configuration > PDF Print-outs > PDF Creation` you can define a `Sender Address Bar`:

[image: FireGento PDF Sender Address Bar]

This will be shown directly above the customer address like this:

[image: FireGento PDF Sender Address Bar in PDF Invoice]